# npx hardhat compile Unexpected token?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hardhat

Was following this [article](https://blog.suhailkakar.com/building-a-full-stack-web3-youtube-clone-with-next-ipfs-the-graph-solidity-and-polygon) ran the command

```
npm install --dev hardhat @nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox
```

got the successful response. However when I try to run the

```
npx hardhat
```

getting `Unexpected token ?` response.

Tried removing the package-local.json. Also tried removing the global installation. Nothing worked.

Comment: make sure you are using correct version of node. try `nvm use 18`

Answer (score 5):

I also got the same error!

```
  ~ npx hardhat Unexpected token '?'
```

After i upgrade my nodejs version to v16.17.0 and npm version to 8.15.0, error is gone

Once the reported error is gone then you should see the below message

```
➜  ~ npx hardhat
888    888                      888 888               888
888    888                      888 888               888
888    888                      888 888               888
8888888888  8888b.  888d888 .d88888 88888b.   8888b.  888888
888    888     "88b 888P"  d88" 888 888 "88b     "88b 888
888    888 .d888888 888    888  888 888  888 .d888888 888
888    888 888  888 888    Y88b 888 888  888 888  888 Y88b.
888    888 "Y888888 888     "Y88888 888  888 "Y888888  "Y888

 Welcome to Hardhat v2.11.2 ‍
```

Answer (score 3):

I have had a similar issue attempting to install hardhat via
`npx hardhat`.

I found the solution from user I Like resolved this. Make sure you are using correct version of node. try `nvm use 18`

```
nvm install 18 
npx hardhat
```

and had success!

Comment: I had to install nvm first, see here for more: https://nvm.sh, then this worked!

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error when I was installing the hardhat:

```
let taskName = parsedTaskName ?? task_names_1.TASK_HELP;

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
```

try this command on your terminal

```
nvm use 18
nvm install 18
```

basically above commands will increase your node.js and npm version

then try to install

```
npx hardhat
```